# Threading: Listen and recognize my speech while performing other tasks in the background

Tags: python, speech-recognition, python-multithreading

I am trying to build my personal voice assistant. The thing that I find difficult is when my program has recognized my speech and doing the thing it's supposed to do when it hears a key word — it just stops listening. Other functions are still working, except for the speech recognition.

```
import random
import time
import datetime
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
from threading import Thread
import pyaudio

engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.setProperty("rate", 165)
voices = engine.getProperty("voices")
engine.setProperty("voice", voices[1].id)

threadlist = []
        
def listening():
    while 2 == 2:
        try:
            with sr.Microphone() as source:
                r = sr.Recognizer()
                print("start listening")
                audio_data = r.listen(source)
                print("Recognizing...")
                global sentence
                text = r.recognize_google(audio_data, language="us-US")
                sentence = text.lower()
                print(sentence)
                if "time" in sentence.split():
                    print("said time")
                    engine.say(f"Right now it is {current_hour} hours and {current_minute} minutes")
                    engine.runAndWait()
                elif "thank" in sentence.split():
                    if "you" in sentence.split():
                        engine.say("You are welcome, sir")
                        engine.runAndWait()
        except:
            print("Failed to recognize the sound")
            text = ""               


def get_datetime():
    while 2 == 2:
        global current_hour
        global current_minute
        global current_day
        print("getting datetime")
        current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()

        current_hour = current_datetime.strftime("%H")
        current_minute = current_datetime.strftime("%M") 
        current_day = current_datetime.strftime("%u") 
        time.sleep(30)

def test():
    i = 0
    while i < 50:
        i = i + 1
        time.sleep(2)
        print(i)

threadlist.append(Thread(target=get_datetime))
threadlist.append(Thread(target=listening))
threadlist.append(Thread(target=test))

for t in threadlist:
    t.start()
for t in threadlist:
    t.join()
```

Comment: Your "bare" `except` is likely hiding the problem. They should be considered syntax errors IMO. At least change it to `except Exception as exc:' and print out any that occur (on the indented line following it).

Comment: thanks, i have completely redone my script so it doesn't have this problem anymore